# Is there any way to subscribe to contract event without creating filter?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, nodes, infura

I developed contract with couple of events. It was tested using local `geth` node and working as expected. Now I want to deploy it and decided to use infura.io as public node provider.

Here I faced show stopping issue: infura provides only limited set or RPC calls and `newFilter` isn't included in this list. I see that while subscribing to events on my contract first `web3` sends `eth_newFilter` call that failed.

I suspect that I can safely remove filter statement from my contract definition:

`this.contract.logWinner({fromBlock:'latest'}).watch(this.onWinner.bind(this));`

and replace it with

`this.contract.logWinner({}).watch(this.onWinner.bind(this));`

but `newFilter` function still calling and crashed app.

My question: could I avoid somehow calling for `eth.newfilter`?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of infura.io API which [does not support `eth_newFilter`](https://infura.io/docs/#supported-json-rpc-methods) you can use [etherscan.io API](https://etherscan.io/apis#logs).

For example here is how to get [EOS](https://etherscan.io/token/EOS) `Transfer` events:

```
const api = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs";
const range = "&fromBlock=379224&toBlock=latest";
const addr = "&address=0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0";
const topic = "&topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef";
fetch(api + range + addr + topic).then(r => r.json).then(console.log);
```

Comment: I do not need to call 3rd party API at all. My question was about absolutely different case.

Comment: Why you are mentioning "show stopping issue: infura provides only limited set or RPC calls" then?